# Javascript sometimes working and sometimes not working without any errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

I have this weird issue where sometimes my javascript is not loaded and not a single error shows up in my console.

If I hard refresh (CTRL SHIFT R) and normal refresh sometimes my page loads with the correct functionalities and other times all are broken.

Why could this be?

And how do I begin to sort out the problem?

This page for example:
https://partykoning.nl/stormbanen-huren/wipe-out-muur-huren

The orange buttons that say 'RESERVEER NU' should not open a new page but instead a small popup text. The large text below should be shortened with a button to read more.

It seems random as to when it works.

I've tried removing parts of my javascript to see where the issue lies but the problem stays.

Also a strange thing is when it loads correctly and everything works, I do get errors in my console, but these errors are old and are unrelated to this issue.

So when the javascript stops working I get 0 errors, when it works I get some unrelated old errors in my console.

What can I do?

Comment: Do you have some try/catch block without message?

Comment: @DouglasOliveira No this problem only appeared recently and I didn't add any try/catch blocks.

Comment: Is the code in question wrapped within a `ready`, or a `DOMContentLoaded`, or some other handler? The described _sometimes happens, sometimes not_ behavior sounds typical of having neither as the browser loads resources. But without any code to see what's been done, no one can assist with a realistic answer, we'd only be guessing.